# Implementing TensorFlow into an already made webpage that uses device webcam

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow, html-helper

I am trying to implement Tensorflow into a webpage. I created that already and has a camera function. Can anyone help me with this?

I'm struggling to find out how to add Tensorflow onto what I already have and all the tutorials that I've followed only shows it working with cameras they have built. Below is the code used for the webpage. It has just simple HTML, CSS and Javascript code.

**HTML:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Lets Scan</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/LetsScan.css">
</head>
<body>
      <!-- Navigation Bar Code-->
<nav class="navbar">
  <a href="Home.html"> Home</a>
  <a href="LetsScan.html">Lets Scan</a>
  <a href="AboutUs.html">About Us</a>
  <a href="ContactUs.html">Contact Us</a>
</nav>

<div class="contentarea">
    <div class="camera">
        <video id="video">Video stream not available.</video>
    </div>
    <div><button id="startbutton">Take photo</button></div>

    <!-- Camera Output -->
    <!--  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div class="output">
        <img id="photo" alt="The screen capture will appear in this box.">
    </div>
  -->

</div>
  <script src="js/letsscan.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**CSS:**

```
       /* Style the top navigation bar */
   .navbar {
    overflow: hidden; /* Hide overflow */
    background-color: #333; /* Dark background color */
  }

  /* Style the navigation bar links */
  .navbar a {
    float: left; /* Make sure that the links stay side-by-side */
    display: block; /* Change the display to block, for responsive reasons (see below) */
    color:  white; /* White text color */
    text-align: center; /* Center the text */
    padding: 14px 20px; /* Add some padding */
    text-decoration: none; /* Remove underline */
  }

  /* Right-aligned link */
  .navbar a.right {
    float: right; /* Float a link to the right */
  }

  /* Change color on hover/mouse-over */
  .navbar a:hover {
    background-color: #ddd; /* Grey background color */
    color: black; /* Black text color */
  }

  /* CSS comes here */
     #video {
         border: 1px solid black;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
     }

     #photo {
         border: 1px solid black;
         width: 100%;
         height: 100%;
     }

     #canvas {
         display: none;
     }

     .camera {
         width: 100%;
         display: inline-block;
     }

     .output {
         width: 500px;
         display: inline-block;
     }

     #startbutton {
         display: block;
         position: relative;
         margin-left: auto;
         margin-right: auto;
         bottom: 36px;
         padding: 5px;
         background-color: #6a67ce;
         border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
         font-size: 14px;
         color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);
         cursor: pointer;
     }

     .contentarea {
         font-size: 16px;
         font-family: Arial;
         text-align: center;
     }
```

**JS:**

```
    /* JS comes here */
 (function() {

     var width = 320; // We will scale the photo width to this
     var height = 0; // This will be computed based on the input stream

     var streaming = false;

     var video = null;
     var canvas = null;
     var photo = null;
     var startbutton = null;

     function startup() {
         video = document.getElementById('video');
         canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
         photo = document.getElementById('photo');
         startbutton = document.getElementById('startbutton');

         navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
                 video: true,
                 audio: false
             })
             .then(function(stream) {
                 video.srcObject = stream;
                 video.play();
             })
             .catch(function(err) {
                 console.log("An error occurred: " + err);
             });

         video.addEventListener('canplay', function(ev) {
             if (!streaming) {
                 height = video.videoHeight / (video.videoWidth / width);

                 if (isNaN(height)) {
                     height = width / (4 / 3);
                 }

                 video.setAttribute('width', width);
                 video.setAttribute('height', height);
                 canvas.setAttribute('width', width);
                 canvas.setAttribute('height', height);
                 streaming = true;
             }
         }, false);

         startbutton.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
             takepicture();
             ev.preventDefault();
         }, false);

         clearphoto();
     }


     function clearphoto() {
         var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
         context.fillStyle = "#AAA";
         context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

         var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
         photo.setAttribute('src', data);
     }

     function takepicture() {
         var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
         if (width && height) {
             canvas.width = width;
             canvas.height = height;
             context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height);

             var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
             photo.setAttribute('src', data);
         } else {
             clearphoto();
         }
     }

     window.addEventListener('load', startup, false);
 })();
```

Any help or direction would be greatly appreciated.